# android : get text data from server(php) and show by textview in android

Tags: android

in my app i have a profile(dialog activity) that send username and pass to server and get Date and show that in user registering time.
this data send from php to android, the php code as follows

```
function get(){

$connection = connectToDatabase();
$Username = $_REQUEST['Username'];
$Pass = $_REQUEST['Pass'];


if($Username!="" && $Pass!=""){

        $result = mysqli_query($connection,"select Date from users where Username='$Username' and Pass='$Pass'");


    $array_finish = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

        $record = array();
        $record['Date'] = $row['Date'];

        $array_finish[] = $record ;
    }

    echo json_encode($array_finish);

}else {

    print "null";

}
mysqli_close($connection);}
```

but i dont know how i can receive Date from php and show in textview
please help me to complete this android code :

```
 private void ShowProfile(){

    profile = new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .customView(R.layout.alert_aprofile,false)
            .show();

    AsyncHttpPost post = new AsyncHttpPost(
            "http://(my server link).php"
    );

    post.setTimeout(5000);
    MultipartFormDataBody body = new MultipartFormDataBody();
    body.addStringPart("Username",sp.getString("Username", null));
    body.addStringPart("Pass",sp.getString("Pass", null));
    post.setBody(body);

    AsyncHttpClient.getDefaultInstance().executeString(post, new AsyncHttpClient.StringCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(final Exception e, AsyncHttpResponse source, final String result) {

                    if (e != null) {
                        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                wait.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "no connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        });
                    }


                    if (!result.equals("")) {
                        MainActivity.activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                items.clone();
                                try {
                                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                        HashMap<String, Object> hash_add = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                                        hash_add.put("Date", object.getString("Date"));

                                        hash_all.add(hash_add);
                                        items = new String[hash_all.size()];
                                    }

                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

});
```

Comment: first of all, add a break point in your application and check if your results variable gets the date back from the PHP call.

Comment: Any new answer?!

Comment: As I stated before, debug the application and see if the results variable contains the data you are looking for.